# Save and download variable in databricks community using python

Tags: python, databricks

I was trying to save and then download a csv (or any) file in Databricks Community. I've spent numerous hours to combine different sources. Following, my solution how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

## Saving and reading files in python/databricks

```
#write a file to DBFS using Python I/O APIs
with open("/dbfs/FileStore/my-stuff/my-file.txt", 'w') as f:
  f.write("Apache Spark is awesome!\n")
  f.write("End of example!")

# read the file
with open("/dbfs/FileStore/my-stuff/my-file.txt", "r") as f_read:
  for line in f_read:
    print(line)
```

Change my-stuff and my-file according to your preferences.

## Downloading the saved files

1. Open in Databricks "Data=>Add Data"
2. Open the tab "DBFS"
3. Select the file you want to download
4. Note the path
   [image: Note the path to the file you want to download]
5. In your current URL, not the number (ID) after `?o=`

*Example: https://community.cloud.databricks.com/?o=**1234567891234567**#tables/new/dbfs*

6. Construct the download URL

*Template:* https://community.cloud.databricks.com/files/my-stuff/my-file.txt?o=######

Replace `my-stuff/my-file.txt` with the path you acquired in step 4, but **without** leading `\FileStore`.

Replace ###### with your ID (acquired in step 5).

Voila - your file should download.